# Can I use a variable instead of a url in curl_setopt ($sh, CURLOPT_URL,

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.0.14:8081/home/');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Change link url

$link = $curl_response;

$linkgo = '/sickbeard_public';
$linkfind = 'href="';
$linkreplace = 'href="' . $linkgo ;

$link = str_replace($linkfind, $linkreplace, $link);


//Change js url
$js = $link;

$jsgo = 'http://192.168.0.14:8081';
$jsfind = 'src="';
$jsreplace = 'src="' . $jsgo ;

$js = str_replace($jsfind, $jsreplace, $js);


//Fix on page link errors
$alink = $js;
$alinkgo = 'http://192.168.0.14:8081/';
$alinkfind = 'a href="/sickbeard_public/';
$alinkreplace = 'a href="' . $alinkgo ;

$alink = str_replace($alinkfind, $alinkreplace, $alink);
_________________

$sh = curl_init();
$url = $alink;
curl_setopt ($sh, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($sh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_res = curl_exec($sh);


echo $curl_res;

?>
```

I'm trying to pull a webpage and then when links on that page are clicked I want the original urls to be curled. The code works up to the line if I have echo $alink; instead of the stuff after the line. But with the code showing above it doesn't. The curling of clicked urls doesn't work. Been fiddling with it for a few hours but google isn't helping and I have no idea what to do now. Please assist..
Thanks

Comment: As far as CURL's concerned, there's absolutely no difference between a hard-coded URL string and a URL stored in a variable. Put some debugging information to echo out `$alink` just before you try to use it in `curl_setop()` - most likely some of that processing you do on it with str_replace() isn't working right.

Comment: I see what you are saying and I think I might be going about this the wrong way.. Confusing myself.. I need any link that has a "a href=" tag when clicked to be received via curl. I can't hard code these links as they are from a dynamic site so could be anything. How would I achieve this?

Comment: "I need any link that has a "a href=" tag when clicked to be received via curl. I can't hard code these links as they are from a dynamic site so could be anything. How would I achieve this?" That's a separate question - ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Will do Jimmy. This question is resolved then as its not a question anymore :) My bad

Answer (score 0):

make sure that all the variable values after "?" are "urlencode()", especially spaces otherwise it won't work.